# Why does SetWindowRgn not work for static controls?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I have some problems with making static controls rounded. I can't understand why SetWindowRgn doesn't work for a static control here. Also I've tried SelectClipRgn and it works. But nevertheless why SetWindowRgn doesn't? The Microsoft documentation states that

> The system does not display any portion of a window that lies outside
>   of the window region.

The control must be rounded and clipped according to the documentation. But it is not. Here's my example of the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    HRGN hrgnMain = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 200, 200, 5, 5);
    int res = SetWindowRgn(hwnd, hrgnMain, TRUE);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    HWND hControl = CreateWindow(L"Static", L"hello, world", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY | SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP,
        20, 20, 40, 40, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    HRGN hrgnControl = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 10, 10, 5, 5);
    res = SetWindowRgn(hControl, hrgnControl, TRUE);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The best think to do is to design a new control from scratch, especially for something simple like a static one.

Comment: In what way exactly is it not working? Please be more specific. Can you show a screenshot of what you are actually seeing, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, the control must be rounded and clipped according to the Microsoft documentation. But it is not.

Comment: @Ken White, first I replied in comments and then edit my question. What kind of details do you want me to provide? The problem is pretty straightforward and clear: SetWindowRgn does not clip controls, while the documentation states the opposite. I put a sample. I think that's quite enough.

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy "*What kind of details do you want me to provide?*" - how about what I asked you to provide? "*SetWindowRgn does not clip controls*" - yes, it does. I've done it before. See [can i use Regions functions with child controls?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fb3aeea4-cb3f-49ab-b298-cf2059b40192/win32-can-i-use-regions-functions-with-child-controls), which leads to [Using SetWindowRgn](http://www.flounder.com/setwindowrgn.htm#Drawing%20the%20Buttons), which talks about using `SetWindowRgn()` for child controls (see "CS_PARENTDC and Clipping Paths").

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thanks for the link, very helpful for understanding what's going on. "Yes, it does" - to be exact, it does only after removing CS_PARENTDC style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some builtin controls use `CS_PARENTDC` class style.

`CS_PARENTDC` sets the clipping region of the child window to that of the parent window. This conflicts with  `SetWindowRgn` which wants to install custom region. Depending how your window is refreshed you could get different combinations of custom region working or not. For example if you resize parent window you can get your control refreshed partially with region set and partially without region.

[image]

[Parent Display Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/parent-display-device-contexts) states that:

> The system ignores the CS_PARENTDC style if the parent window uses a
>   private or class device context, if the parent window clips its child
>   windows, or if the child window clips its child windows or sibling
>   windows.

But it looks that setting only `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for parent windows is not enough. Adding `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` or `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flags in control styles (even if you have only one child) triggers desired behavior.

```
HWND hControl = CreateWindow(
                    L"Static",
                    L"hello, world",
                    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY | SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP,
                    20, 20, 40, 40,
                    hwnd,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL);
```

Your code without `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`

[image: Without WS_CLIPSIBLINGS]

And with `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`

[image: With WS_CLIPSIBLINGS]

Alternatively the `CS_PARENT` style could be removed by using `GetClassLongPtr` and `SetClassLongPtr`. Because `CS_PARENT` is used only to reuse clipping region it shouldn't have any other unexpected effects.

```
SetClassLongPtr(
        hControl,
        GCL_STYLE,
        GetClassLongPtr( hControl, GCL_STYLE ) & ~CS_PARENTDC );
```

Comment: You can also provide information about CS_PARENTDC style, which is, apparently, specified for standard controls. I've just checked style bits of control's WNDCLASSW and they do have CS_PARENTDC bit. After removing it by replacing GCL_STYLE everything works as expected.