# Custom rounded button using win32

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, rounded-corners, custom-button

I want to create a custom button using Win32. After searching, I found a group of methods, including using `BS_OWNERDRAW`, and I got the desired result and this is when the button is rectangular, but when I wanted to create a rounded button, I faced a problem, which is the appearance of a white background behind the button and despite a lot of research, I did not find the right way to get rid of the white background. I hope you can help me.

This is the code I used:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    // Define window properties variables
    const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    // Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to register window class", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Creating the window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"myWindowClass", L"New Window",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                            500, 350, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create window", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    // Message loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND buttonHandle;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // cretae the button
        buttonHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"OK",
                                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW,
                                    50, 50, 200, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // fill the window with a solid color
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);
        DeleteObject(hBrush);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

        // Get button rectangle
        RECT buttonRect = lpdis->rcItem;

        // Create Gdiplus::Graphics object from device context
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(lpdis->hDC);
        graphics.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias); // Set anti-alias mode for smoother edges
        // Define button color with alpha channel (transparency)
        Gdiplus::Color buttonColor = Gdiplus::Color(255, 170, 70, 70);

        // Create solid brush for button color
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush brush(buttonColor);
        int x = buttonRect.left;
        int y = buttonRect.top;
        int width = buttonRect.right - buttonRect.left;
        int height = buttonRect.bottom - buttonRect.top;
        // Draw a rounded rectangle
        int cornerRadius = 40;
        Gdiplus::GraphicsPath path;
        path.AddArc(x, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(x, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        graphics.FillPath(&brush, &path);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result was as follows

[image: rounded button win32]

---

**UPDATE:**

Among the answers provided below is an answer from *Remy Lebeau*.
The first method did not work.

The second method, where you use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, gave a result closer to what is required, but with some impurities, as in the picture.

[image: ٌRemy Lebeau answer]

**UPDATE 2:**

The first method provided by *Remy Lebeau* is successful after adding `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` , but I lost the smooth edges feature, and this is a picture of the result :

[image: remy lebeau result update]

We can get the same result using the second method if we do not use `SetSmoothingMode`, but here we also lose the advantage of smooth edges.

Comment: Thank you for your interaction . I tried it . I added SetBkMode( lpdis->hDC, TRANSPARENT ) to the code , but the result is still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you are calling `GdiplusStartup()` in the wrong place.  By having it at the top of `MainWndProc()`, you are calling it for *every* message that your window receives.  You need to call `GdiplusStartup()` only once, so move in into `WinMain()` instead.  And also, you need to call `GdiplusShutdown()` before exiting from `WinMain()`.

Now, that being said, your button has a default rectangular shape, but you are simply not drawing it as a rectangle.  That is why you are seeing the white areas.

You can use [`CreateRoundRectRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createroundrectrgn) and [`SetWindowRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn) to give the button a true non-rectangular shape to match your drawing.

For example:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    // Starting GDI+
    if (GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) != Status::Ok)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to start GDI+", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Registering the Window Class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to register window class", L"Error", MB_OK);
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
        return 1;
    }

    // Creating the window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, L"New Window",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                            500, 350, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create window", L"Error", MB_OK);
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
        return 1;
    }

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    // Message loop
    MSG Msg;
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    
    return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // create the button
        HWND buttonHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"OK",
                                    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW,
                                    50, 50, 200, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        // create a region to shape the button
        HRGN hRgn = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 200, 100, 40, 40);
        SetWindowRgn(buttonHandle, hRgn, TRUE);
        break;
    }

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

        // Get button rectangle
        RECT buttonRect = lpdis->rcItem;
        int x = buttonRect.left;
        int y = buttonRect.top;
        int width = buttonRect.right - buttonRect.left;
        int height = buttonRect.bottom - buttonRect.top;

        // Create Graphics object from device context
        Graphics graphics(lpdis->hDC);
        graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias); // Set anti-alias mode for smoother edges

        // Create solid brush for button color
        SolidBrush brush(Color(170, 70, 70));
        // Draw a rounded rectangle
        int cornerRadius = 40;
        GraphicsPath path;
        path.AddArc(x, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(x, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        graphics.FillPath(&brush, &path);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, on Windows 8+ you can assign the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style to the button (prior to Win8, `WS_EX_LAYERED` works only on top-level windows), and then use [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) or [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow) to make the button have true transparency in the areas that you don't want to draw.

For example:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    // Starting GDI+
    if (GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) != Status::Ok)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to start GDI+", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Registering the Window Class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to register window class", L"Error", MB_OK);
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
        return 1;
    }

    // Creating the window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, L"New Window",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                            500, 350, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create window", L"Error", MB_OK);
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
        return 1;
    }

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    // Message loop
    MSG Msg;
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    
    return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // create the button
        HWND buttonHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, L"BUTTON", L"OK",
                                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW,
                                    50, 50, 200, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        // set button transparent color (fuchsia)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(buttonHandle, RGB(255, 0, 255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
        break;
    }

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

        // Get button rectangle
        RECT buttonRect = lpdis->rcItem;
        int x = buttonRect.left;
        int y = buttonRect.top;
        int width = buttonRect.right - buttonRect.left;
        int height = buttonRect.bottom - buttonRect.top;

        // Create Graphics object from device context
        Graphics graphics(lpdis->hDC);
        graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias); // Set anti-alias mode for smoother edges

        // Create solid brush for button background color (fuchsia)
        SolidBrush bkgBrush(Color(255, 0, 255));
        // Draw the background
        graphics.FillRectangle(&bkgBrush, x, y, width, height);

        // Create solid brush for button color
        SolidBrush buttonBrush(Color(170, 70, 70));
        // Draw a rounded rectangle
        int cornerRadius = 40;
        GraphicsPath path;
        path.AddArc(x, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - cornerRadius, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(x, y + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        graphics.FillPath(&buttonBrush, &path);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interaction. I have read some articles about what you told me, but I hope that if there is an example of the code, you can provide a link if possible.

Comment: I actually tried  CreateRoundRectRgn() and SetWindowRgn() and used them with BS_PUSHBUTTON inside WM_CREATE and WM_PAINT, and also with BS_OWNERDRAW inside WM_DRAWITEM, but without getting the desired result.

Comment: @stepicGame I have added examples

Comment: Thanks for providing code examples
The first example, where using CreateRoundRectRgn() and SetWindowRgn() did not give the desired result, but the background remained visible.
The second example, where you use SetLayeredWindowAttributes() or UpdateLayeredWindow(), gave a result that was closest to what was required, as the background was removed, but some blemishes remained on the edges.

Comment: I added a picture of the result to the main question. Is there a way to overcome the problem?

Comment: Regarding the `SetWindowRgn()` approach, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118211/. I have updated my example for that and now it works. Regarding the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` approach, the artifacts on the edges are because the edges are being drawn with anti-aliasing, so using a color-key for transparency won't match up with the colors 100% along the edges. A region can avoid that, but a region can't have anti-aliased edges. So, you will have to use a slightly larger region in the 1st approach, or draw a different color behind the anti-aliased areas in the 2nd approach.

Comment: The first method is successful after adding WS_CLIPSIBLINGS ,
but I lost the smooth edges feature, and I will add a picture of the result in the main question . 
As for the second method, I do not understand exactly how to draw a different color behind the anti-aliased areas

Comment: What I mean is, simply draw a different background color a few pixels out from the edges, so the anti-aliasing merges with that color instead of the transparent color, and then draw the transparent color for the rest of the background you want hidden. As long as the parent window has the same/similar color as the anti-aliased color, you shouldn't notice a difference.